# return JSON using JAX-RS Pojo class with Generic Type member?

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

When I return a class with Generic Type member in restful and JAX-RS with GlassFish server. 
I got error code 500.

The Class define like this:

> Public Class Result {
>           private int resultCode=1;
>           private T data;
>       }

Or the member T data change to List data.

I test many way like using GenericEntity class. But GenericEntity way only success using like this?

> GenericEntity> entity = new GenericEntity>(list){};

Could any one give me some advise?